# Why were early studies on morpheme acquisition criticized?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition

I was reading the Wikipedia page on [Order of acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_acquisition) and they said that many studies in the 1970s studied "whether a consistent order of morpheme acquisition", e.g. in L2 learners for English.  But these studies were "widely criticized, as insufficient attention was given to the overuse of these features."

What is meant by this?  I don't quite understand the nature of the criticism.

Comment: Actually, that's an unsupported assertion made on 15 Dec 2010, so the appropriate question would be "What evidence is there that this is true?" Funny that they only citation-tag the "flurry of studies" statement and not the "widely criticized" assertion. It's not about the meaning, it's about the evidence.

Comment: You can start with Murakami, A., & Alexopoulou, T. (2016). L1 influence on the acquisition order of English grammatical morphemes: A Learner Corpus Study. Studies in Second Language Acquisition, 38(3), 365-401. doi:10.1017/S0272263115000352 , see "Literature Review" there https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/studies-in-second-language-acquisition/article/l1-influence-on-the-acquisition-order-of-english-grammatical-morphemes/3263C3E82ECA4A7EB19D8F50E45FA1C3

Comment: @user6726 The [15 Dec 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Order_of_acquisition&diff=402461293) edit didn't change the article body. The current wording dates back to [22 July 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Order_of_acquisition&diff=565368392), but the passage was already in [the oldest revision of "Second language acquisition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Second-language_acquisition&oldid=7771305) from 2004, which was then split into "Order of acquisition" in 2010.

Comment: The passage seems to have been based on [Ellis (1994: 95)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3KglibyrZ5sC&pg=PA95).